# Flink generate TypeInformation dynamically

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to parse a nested field in a row of a data stream through RichMapFunction<Row, Row>. The input and output of this is Row type. This nested column in a row can have any number of fields.

```
DataStream<Row> outStream =  stream.map(new ParsePayload(functionMap, inputTypeInformation))
        .returns(<output TypeInformation>)
        .uid("ParseNestedColumn");

private static class ParsePayload extends RichMapFunction<Row, Row> implements Serializable
{
@Override
public Row map(Row row) throws Exception {
    <business logic>
    …….
    return resultRow;
}
}
```

The issue is that, I want to return type information of a row only after evaluating map function or by creating output row because fields in a row are not fixed.

I have tried both Types.ROW_NAMED() and ResultTypeQueryable interface, but both checks type information before evaluating map function and this way I can’t supply type information to the stream.

P.S - I do not want to enable Generic Types for my job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

If You think about this `TypeInformation` is used to generate serializers that are required by the source for example, so You would create a cyclic dependency here (the source requires `TypeInformation` to pass the data to `map`, but it can't because `map` needs to first provide `TypeInformation`).

There are different possible ways of doing that, but all of them require either using `Generic*` classes or getting the data in form of `byte[]` or `String` and parsing to expected type manually, or trying to implement custom type that could represent all the possibilities You need to handle.